# How to predict with multiple features in Php-ai/Php-ml in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, artificial-intelligence, php-ml

I am using the [Php-ai/Php-ml](https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml) framework. In the [example they give](https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml-examples/blob/master/classification/languageDetection.php), the AI only uses one feature which is not helpful but on the main git page, they also give this example of using more than one feature:

```
$samples = [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 1], [4, 1], [4, 2]];
$labels = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'];

$classifier = new KNearestNeighbors();
$classifier->train($samples, $labels);

echo $classifier->predict([3, 2]);
```

Based on the example supplying only one feature, and the secondary example supplying two. I tried to recreate this:

I am trying to recreate this using two features. My current code snippet looks like this:

```
public function train(Request $request) {

    # CSV File
    $file = $request->file('dataframe');

    # Features + 1 will be the labels column
    $dataset = new CsvDataset($file, (int) $request->features);

    $vectorizer = new TokenCountVectorizer(new WordTokenizer());
    $tfIdfTransformer = new TfIdfTransformer();

    $finalSamples = [];
    for($i = 0; $i <= $request->features -1; $i++):
        $samples = [];
        foreach ($dataset->getSamples() as $sample)
            $samples[] = $sample[$i];

        $vectorizer->fit($samples);
        $vectorizer->transform($samples);

        $tfIdfTransformer->fit($samples);
        $tfIdfTransformer->transform($samples);

        $finalSamples[] = $samples;
    endfor;

    # This gives us an output of Array[ 0 => [Feature 1, Feature 2], 1 => [Feature 1, Feature 2], ... ] like shown on example two.

    $result = [];
    foreach($finalSamples as $arr)
        foreach($arr as $k => $v)
            $result[$k][] = $v;

    $dataset = new ArrayDataset($result, $dataset->getTargets());
    $randomSplit = new StratifiedRandomSplit($dataset, 0.1);

    $classifier = new SVC(Kernel::RBF, 10000);

    # Train with half of the data frame
    $classifier->train($randomSplit->getTrainSamples(), $randomSplit->getTrainLabels());

    $predictedLabels = $classifier->predict($randomSplit->getTestSamples());
    $inputLabels     = $randomSplit->getTestLabels();
}
```

My CSV file looks like this:

```
"SibSp","Parch","Survived",
"1", "1", "1",
"3", "3", "1",
"4", "1", "0"
"4", "0", "1",
"5", "2", "0"
"3", "1", "0",
"2", "2", "1",
"0", "0", "1"
```

The problem now is when I visualise the data, which I do like so:

```
$newDataFrame   = [];
$incorrect      = 0;

for($i = 0; $i <= count($inputLabels) -1; $i++):
    $newDataFrame[] = (object) ['input' => $inputLabels[$i], 'output' => $predictedLabels[$i]];
    if($inputLabels[$i] != $predictedLabels[$i]) $incorrect++;
ndfor;

$correct = count($inputLabels) - $incorrect;
$score   = round((float)Accuracy::score(isset($request->train) ? $randomSplit->getTestLabels() : $inputLabels, $predictedLabels) * 100 );
```

The data always comes out as 1 correct, 1 incorrect and sits at a score of 50 (%).

How can I use this Classifier to use multiple features rather than just one? I think the problem is when building the `ArrayDataSet` but I have no clue what is wrong with it.